# List index out of range for more words

Tags: python, wordnet

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

s=0
file1 = open("File1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("features_mobile.txt","r")     
outputFile = open("File2.txt", "w")
list1, list2, list = [], [], []

list1 = [(wordnet.synsets(word)[0]) for word in file1.read().splitlines()]
list2 = [(wordnet.synsets(word)[0]) for word in file2.read().splitlines()]
```

I'm getting error if File1.txt has more than 3 words.
Its content is like this
camera
lens
processor
battery
body 
for these many words it's giving error saying list: inde out of range
and for three words it runs fine
what do I do??

Comment: Possibly it's not the number of words, but there might be a double newline in the input? i.e. try checking `file1.read().splitlines()` and see if it's got an empty string in the list, `''`. That would make the `[0]` index out of range.

Comment: @Roberto `splitlines` removes the `''`

Comment: @A.J. not if it's a double newline, `'one\n\ntwo'.splitlines()` is `['one', '', 'two']`

Comment: There is no empty string.

Comment: @MonikaBhajani ok, then could you please update the question and post the complete Traceback of the error?

Comment: @MonikaBhajani in lack of the Traceback, one other obvious question - are all words found in the dictionary? Won't you get such an error if a word isn't there?